# Ajax getting undefined a well formatted JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, undefined, response

I have read most of the entries here referencing "ajax response undefined" but none of them worked for me or they were not related. I hope not to create a duplicated here. Here goes the issue.

I have a well formatted JSON. I ask the php using Postman and the Json appears as it should. I have tried online tools checking the integrity of the Json and it is fine too. 
However, when it comes to the ajax response, it is automatically undefined. The whole response is undefined. Here's the code.

Php:

```
    require_once dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/new/config/config.inc.php';
require_once dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/new/init.php';
require 'producto.php';
require 'Conjunto.php';
$array_referencias = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['seleccionProductos']));
$imagenes_principales = [
    "jardin.jpg",
    "ceramicas1.jpg"
];
$host_name = 'xx';
$database = 'xx';
$user_name = 'xx';
$password = 'xx';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Se ha produción un error de conexión SQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$id_got = array();
$x = 0;
while ($array_referencias[$x] != null) {
    $y = 0;
    while ($array_referencias[$x][$y] != null) {
        $current_ref = $array_referencias[$x][$y];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT p.id_product FROM ps_product p where p.reference = '$current_ref'");
        foreach (mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) as $key => $value) {
            $id_got[$x][$y] = $value;
        }
        $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
$conn->close();
$conjuntos = array();
$n = 0;
while ($id_got[$n] != null) {
    $o = 0;
    $unidad_prod = array();
    while ($id_got[$n][$o] != null) {
        $id_a_usar = $id_got[$n][$o];
        $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $product = new Product($id_a_usar, false, $id_lang);
        $img = $product->getCover($product->id);
        $image_type = 'small_default'; //Mirar el ftp para ver otros tipos
        $producto = new producto();
        $producto->setNombre(strtoupper($product->name));
        $producto->setPrecio($product->price);
        $producto->setImagen($link->getImageLink(isset($product->link_rewrite) ? $product->link_rewrite : $product->name, (int)$img['id_image'], $image_type));
        $producto->setUrl(Context::getContext()->link->getProductLink($id_a_usar));
        $unidad_prod[] = $producto;
        $o++;
    }
    $conjunto = new Conjunto();
    $conjunto->setImagenprincipal($imagenes_principales[$n]);
    $conjunto->setProductos($unidad_prod);
    $conjuntos[] = $conjunto;
    $n++;
}
$res = json_encode($conjuntos);
echo $res;
```

JS:

```
 function request() {
     var refs_en_foto1=[10078,28352,32704,28300,14569,4161,28306,18818,3160,8435,8438,8436,21016,8437,19568,15365,31963,20145,40381,19961,40380,36001];
     var refs_en_foto2=[15365,31963,20145];
     var referencias = [refs_en_foto1,refs_en_foto2];
     var contenidohtml="";
     var x,i=0,y=0;

     for (y in referencias){
         var jsonString = JSON.stringify(referencias[y]);
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'gallery_connect.php',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {seleccionProductos: jsonString },
             error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 console.log("Se produjo el siguiente error: "+error);
             },
             success: function (response) {
**Code doesn't work from here, response is fully 'undefined'**
                    contenidohtml+="<div class='galeria'><div class='contenedor_izq'><img src='"+response[0].imagenprincipal+
                    "'/></div><div class='contenedor_der'>";
                    for(x in response) {
                        contenidohtml+="<div class='caja_articulo'><div class='imagen_articulo'><img id='img1' src='"+response[0].productos[0].imagen+
                            "'/></div><div class='filas_texto'>"+response[0].productos[0].nombre+"</div>";
                        contenidohtml+="<div class='filas_texto botongaleria noselect'><a href='"+response[0].productos[0].url+"'>VER PRODUCTO</a></div></div>"
                         }
                    contenidohtml+="</div></div>";
             }
         });
         y++;
         i++;
     }
     document.getElementById("foto1").innerHTML = contenidohtml;
 }
```

The error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagenprincipal' of
>   undefined at Object.success (custom.js:28) at u (jquery.min.js:2) at
>   Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2) at k
>   (jquery.min.js:2) at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Any Errors/Warnings/Notices before you see `undefined`?  Did you check your error logs?  Are there any other (potential) echoed / displayed text in the "irrelevant" part of your php code?  Did you strip back your php code until you _could_ get an expected result?  How about a static, manually written json string that doesn't actually engage any of your current processes?

Comment: Check what the actual response to the AJAX request is in your browser dev tools, network panel. If you do not see the JSON data as expected there, then your server-side script did not return what you expected in the first place, so you’ll know that you need to start looking there.

Comment: This is what it shows in the console, it just gets 'undefined':
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagenprincipal' of undefined
    at Object.success (custom.js:28)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Actually `imagenprincipal` is undefined where do you set it's value? try to console.log it. Console.log also the response that your ajax returns to see what's there.

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` inside your "success" and see what actual JSON you're getting back (or just look at the request in your browser's network tools, of course). You say "response is fully 'undefined'" but actually technically the error is saying that `response[0]` is undefined. So check your structure carefully.

Comment: Aside from all that, `document.getElementById("foto1").innerHTML = contenidohtml;` will be useless because it executes before you've populated `contenidohtml` with any data. Remember that AJAX calls are asynchronous...you need to append your HTML to the "foto1" element directly within the "success" function. And of course, since you triggered multiple ajax calls simultaneously from within the loop, the HTML may not always get appended in exactly the order you were expecting...it's unclear if that would be a problem in this case or not.

Comment: @misorude But how comes Postman is able to get the Json? The response in both cases should be the same, no matter 'who' is asking for it. 
- I have checked the Newtwork tab and I can't find the php.

Comment: @ADyson no, that part is fine, in previous tests it was compiling the html without problems.

Comment: @Germán based on the code above you should see at least one (but probably two) calls to gallery_connect.php listed in your network tab (important: you have to open the tab _before_ you run the code)...then click into each one and find the Response tab for that request to see what was sent back. I don't think you're not getting the JSON at all, see my comment above, the error is about a specific section of the object, not the whole thing.

Comment: " no, that part is fine"...what were you doing in your previous test? Based on what you've written above, it would not work properly. Unless outside this snippet you've already globally set all ajax requests to be synchronous (which, by the way is a horrible antipattern which you should not use, and is also deprecated anyway)

Comment: _“But how comes Postman is able to get the Json? The response in both cases should be the same, no matter 'who' is asking for it.”_ - if they aren’t, then you probably didn’t manage to make them _ask_ the exact same thing in the first place.

Comment: @ADyson I got the two calls in Network tab (thanks for telling I had to open it before) and both of them return [] meaning an empty array. This is weird. I call the php file using the software Postman and it actually returns a whole json.

Comment: in that case you should look again at the network tab and compare what is being _sent_ in the request, compared to what you send in PostMan. Unfortunately you haven't shown us the bit in PHP where you try to deserialise the JSON, I suspect that would give us a clue about what structure PHP is expecting.

Comment: @ADyson edited and added the full php. I'm suspecting that the error might be in the ajax? I have no clue.

Comment: I know you haven't....but in my last comment I told you where to start looking for clues

Comment: A separate note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like in each request you'll send a flat, one-dimensional array, e.g. `[15365,31963,20145]` (for the second request)...but in the PHP it starts looking for items in a multi-dimensional array (i.e. the line including `$array_referencias[$x][$y]`). Since the array is flat, this value doesn't exist, so it will never execute any SQL. So perhaps the PHP is actually expecting you to send all of `referencias` in one single request. Again, compare it to what you sent in PostMan. If you're unsure, maybe upload a screenshot of your PostMan showing the request data.

Comment: @ADyson I just noticed this error due to recent changes. I also modified the query to make it safe to injections. I don't fully get why in the query of bobby-tables there should be a "si" before the variables. Edit: Nevermind, just checked the documentation.

Comment: @Germán try [reading the relevant documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) ...it's a simple list of characters, each of which describes the data type of the corresponding parameter being submitted (they are matched according to their position in the list).

Comment: Anyway does my suggestion regarding the array structure solve your problem?

Comment: @ADyson Well, the problem presented here was yes, that I was sending an array and it was expecting several arrays. Now I have modified the php in a way it is returning nothing... sigh. I think I have to restart writing everything. Drawbacks of the beginner.